# Mathematica Not Evaluating Small Input

Tags: numerics, special-functions

So I'm a bit confused. I asked Mathematica to evaluate

```
PolyLog[3, -4.900612445719819`*^-15 + 8.488109744191103`*^-15 I]
```

and it refused to do so

[image]

I assume it has something to do with the values being "too small", since It seems to work fine for other values, e.g.

[image]

Does anyone know how to make Mathematica evaluate this input?

Comment: Do you get a warning that looks like "General::munfl: Internal`AbsSquare[-8.94349*10^-198-1.75784*10^-198 I] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost." ?

Comment: Applying the definition almost directly:  `z = Rationalize[-4.900612445719819*^-15 + 8.488109744191103*^-15 I, 0]; n = 3; NSum[z^k/k^n, {k, 1, \[Infinity]}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

It's a precision issue, don't use machine precision.

Use [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) so that the calculation can be done with arbitrary-precision

```
N[
 PolyLog @@
  ({3, -4.900612445719819`*^-15 + 8.488109744191103`*^-15 I} // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] &),
 25]

(* -4.900612445719824749854156*10^-15 + 8.488109744191092161335110*10^-15 I )

% // N

(* -4.90061*10^-15 + 8.48811*10^-15 I *)
```

Alternatively, use [`SetPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html)

```
PolyLog @@
 SetPrecision[
  {3, -4.900612445719819`*^-15 + 8.488109744191103`*^-15 I},
  25]

(* -4.900612445719825135980700*10^-15 + 8.488109744191092254166590*10^-15 I *)

% // N

(* -4.90061*10^-15 + 8.48811*10^-15 I *)
```